# Crashing on push to Heroku with Node.js Express Server with Sockets.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, express

I'm having trouble deploying to Heroku. I have succeeded in doing this in the past and the basic setup and servers of both Apps are the same. However one fails and one works.

A lot of the related StackOverflow posts seem to talk about the server port assigned by Heroku, but I have implemented this in the same way as my other App which works fine.

Cheers.

My logs:

```
2014-07-10T14:49:20+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-07-10T14:49:25+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-07-10T14:49:25.546726+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by **email-address--omitted**
2014-07-10T14:49:25.546616+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e8c1330 by **email-address--omitted**
2014-07-10T14:49:53.489816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=**url-omitted**.herokuapp.com request_id=5feccc8e-b061-4397-aac1-6fdba4de4350 fwd="81.136.226.96" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-10T14:49:53.682090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=**url-omitted**.herokuapp.com request_id=e26c4e91-465a-460c-9135-86106aa2a7c1 fwd="81.136.226.96" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My Proc file:

```
web: node server.js
```

My server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');   
var socket = require('socket.io');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server);



app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  var ua;
  ua = request.headers['user-agent'];
  if (/mobile/i.test(ua)) {
    app.use(express["static"](path.join(__dirname, '')));
    return response.sendfile(__dirname + "/mobile.html");
  } else {
    app.use(express["static"](path.join(__dirname, '')));
    response.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
  }
});


...stuff here related to Socket.io


var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8080);
server.listen(port, function() {
  return console.log('listening on ' + port);
});
```

**Update**

There were no web dynos running for some reason. I scaled to 1, and then got this crash log

```
2014-07-10T15:22:52.447054+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by jack.wild@live.co.uk
2014-07-10T15:23:00.827317+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830741+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830749+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830756+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-07-10T15:23:00.823228+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830736+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830744+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830752+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830742+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-07-10T15:23:00.824793+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830746+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830751+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830754+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-07-10T15:23:00.820120+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-10T15:23:00.830748+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:77)
2014-07-10T15:23:02.996355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-07-10T15:23:02.996355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-10T15:23:07.904191+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2014-07-10T15:23:08.722329+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726092+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726089+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726087+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726102+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726090+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726094+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:77)
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726084+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726100+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726095+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726097+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-07-10T15:23:08.722955+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-07-10T15:23:08.723007+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-07-10T15:23:08.726099+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-07-10T15:23:09.957885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-10T15:23:09.945248+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-07-10T15:22:59.038221+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2014-07-10T15:23:08.722675+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-07-10T15:23:02.979682+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
```

Comment: Also curiously when i do $heroku ps nothing shows up regarding my dynos. It pauses for a couple of seconds and then goes back to cd$

Comment: @BenFortune my logs are in the question... are there other logs I can access?

Comment: There were no web dynos running for some reason. I scaled to 1, and then got this crash log

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I had added express to devDependencies, not dependencies.